# How to do literal replacement to format expression?

Tags: replacement, display

I can do a replacement of an expression with some variables to alternate symbols:

```
{sx^2, sxy} /. {sx -> Subscript[J, x], 
                sxy ->  Subscript[J, x] Subscript[J, y]}
```

but if this replacement includes matching square braces, for example instead of $J_x$ above using:

```
{sx^2, sxy} /. {sx -> [Subscript[J, x]], 
                sxy -> [ Subscript[J, x] Subscript[J, y]]}
```

then the replacement fails with:

```
Expression cannot begin with "[Subscript[J, x]]".
```

I'd like this replacement (only for display purposes) to be $sx  \rightarrow [J_x]$, where square brackets is the notation we are using in class for an "ensemble average".

Is there a way to escape the square braces so that the sequence '[', J_x, ']' will be treated as an opaque entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility:

```
MakeBoxes[Subscript[J_, x_], StandardForm] := 
        RowBox[{"[", SubscriptBox[ToString@J, ToString@x], "]"}]
```

Then evaluating

```
{sx^2, sxy} /. 
   {sx -> Subscript[J, x], sxy -> Subscript[J, x] Subscript[J, y]}
```

should return what you want.

[image]

**Another proposition**

One can also directly use `MakeBoxes` definitions for the variables `sx`, `sy`, and so on...

```
MakeBoxes[sx, StandardForm] := 
        RowBox[{"[", SubscriptBox["J", "x"], "]"}]
```

This avoids using rules as was done above, but it requires defining `MakeBoxes` for every variable (though I suppose this process could be automated without much trouble).

Comment: I figured out after I posted that I could use Row[ "[", ... ] in a replacement expression, but I like your suggestion much better, since it takes the formatting decisions out of the core content.

Comment: Glad you find these propositions useful. Here is yet another possibility: `Format[sx] := DisplayForm[RowBox[{"[", SubscriptBox["J", "x"], "]"}]]`.